# How to include multiple tables with rails 2.3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[image]
As the attached screenshot describes, there are three tables. A has multiple Bs and C has multiple Bs. There is no relationship between A and C.

On the circumstance, when finding A's records, is it possible to include B and C?

B can easily be included by `A.all(:conditions => { :id => id }, :include => [:B])`.
However, I do not know how to include C even if I googled for many hours.

=====================
rails version: 2.3.5
ruby version: 1.8.7

Comment: Did you try `:include => [:A, :B]`? Its going to be hard to find any resources at all for Rails 2 unfortunately since its so ancient.

Comment: Ruby on Rails 2.3.5 was released 12 years ago. IMO it is a terrible idea to still run and extend such an old version. On the one hand, you will have a hard time finding docs and maintaining dependencies. On the other hand, there are [many security vulnerabilities](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=Ruby+on+Rails) in such ancient versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3/active_record_querying.html#nested-associations-hash my guess would be that the following would work.

```
A.all(:conditions => { :id => id }, :include => { :B => :C })
```

Comment: I highly appreciate for your answer. I could include C table.